# Loading Url params using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass some URL params using react-router but I don't get access to the params I pass and the page doesn't.

Here is where I render the router:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  HashRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";

window.React = React;

render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <HashRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path path="/list-days" component={App} />
        <Route
          path="list-days/:filter"
          render={props => <App globalstore={globalstore} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route path="/add-day" component={App} />
        <Route component={Whoops404} />
      </HashRouter>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here are the links that pass the params：

```
            <td colSpan={4}>
              <Link to="/list-days">All Days</Link>
              <Link to={"/list-days/powder"}>Powder</Link>
              <Link to={"/list-days/backcountry"}>Backcountry</Link>
            </td>
```

And here is where I try to pass the params

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Menu />
        {this.props.location.pathname === "/" ? (
          <SkiDayCount
            total={this.countDays()}
            powder={this.countDays("powder")}
            backcountry={this.countDays("backcountry")}
          />
        ) : this.props.location.pathname === "/add-day" ? (
          <AddDayForm />
        ) : (
          <SkiDayList
            days={this.state.allSkiDays}
            filter={this.props.routeParams}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you please include the code snippet for routeParams

Comment: @Harikrishnan I am trying to pass the params with the links I have shown above

Comment: have you tried this.props.match.params.filter to get the params

Comment: @Harikrishnan yes I did. `this.props.match.params.filter` returns undefined

Comment: can you please include your code in codesandbox if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are mentioning `:filter` as dynamic url

```
<Route
          path="list-days/:filter"
          render={props => <App globalstore={globalstore} {...props} />}
        />
```

and passing static urls.

```
<Link to="/list-days">All Days</Link>
<Link to={"/list-days/powder"}>Powder</Link>
<Link to={"/list-days/backcountry"}>Backcountry</Link>
```

Instead You need to give variable like  `<Link to=/list-days/${var}>All Days</Link>`